# Why does \@checkend occur after running \endenvironment?

Tags: environments, latex-base

Does anyone know why in the LaTeX definition of `\end`, the `\@checkend` command occurs after running the end environment code? It seems like for error catching purposes, it would be best to let the user know that something is wrong as soon as possible.

I ask this because I'm developing a couple environments `enva` and `envb` and accidentally saying

```
\begin{enva}
% some stuff
\end{envb}
```

throws some low level error inside of `\endenvb`. In order to prevent this, I have to put my own `\@checkend` style check inside of `\endenvb`, which seems like part of what `\begin` and `\end` were supposed to do for me.

As a simple example of this problem, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\test{}
\begin{test}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\endtikzpicture ...r@layerlist@globally \endscope 
                                                  \let \pgf@baseline =\pgf@s...
l.10 \end{tikzpicture}
```

which is less illuminating than I would desire. I want to prevent similar useless errors from appearing in my own code.

For reference, what I've done to get around this is to write the following command, which I put at the beginning of the `\end` code for each of my environments:

```
% #1 -- the name of the environment being ended
\def\mypkg@checkend#1{
    \def\mypkg@tempa{#1}
    \ifx\mypkg@tempa\@currenvir\else % mismatch
        \mypkg@error{endenv-mismatch}
        \csname end\@currenvir\endcsname % run the \end code for the correct environment
        \def\@currenvir{#1} % Prevent \@checkend from throwing a second redundant error
        \expandafter\mypkg@break % don't run the rest of \endthisenvironment
    \fi
}
```

Comment: A full MWE is missing, but I would be not surprised, if hacking into `\@checkend` will cause trouble with nested environment definitions.

Comment: So you're concerned about someone defining another environment that is a wrapper around mine, and then that causing trouble? I'll do some testing and see if I run into any problems. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I don't see what harm my solution could cause though, because the changed value of `\@checkend` is local and only lasts until it goes out of scope when the `\endgroup` inside of `\end` happens. So it only prevents `\@checkend` from causing a duplicate error message and then goes out of scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An implementation of an environment can contain other environments:

```
\newenvironment{foo}{\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
```

If `\@checkend` would be called right at the begin of the "end" code, it would be called inside `center`, here. The `\@checkend` *after* the "end" part (`\end<environment>`) allows that other environments opened in the "begin" part are closed properly.

Comment: Oh I see. That's unfortunate. So is it recommended practice that if my code might throw an error before it reaches `\@checkend` that I should run a similar check myself? I've never noticed anyone doing this.

Comment: @HoodChatham I have no idea, what you are doing, how environments `enva` and `envb` are defined. With dummy definitions, I get a clear `LaTeX error: \begin{enva} on input line 3 ended by \end{envb}.`.

Comment: So my definition of the `envb` startup code does some setup stuff and then `\endenvb` expects that setup code to have been run, and if it hasn't been then it causes an error.

Comment: @HoodChatham Maybe, you can set a switch/define a macro locally that the setup code of `envb` has been run and test the switch/macro in the end part of `envb`.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. If it seems like the solution I gave above is creating problems, then I'll try out that method.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378179), also notice that it may be necessary for the end-of-environment code to work by expansion where tables are involved. One can see this without moving the (unexpandable) definition by making an `\end...` macro protected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{foo}[1]
  {\begin{tabular}{#1}}{\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \begin{foo}{ccc}
    \hline
    Test & a & b \\
    \hline
  \end{foo}
}
\protected\edef\endfoo{\unexpanded\expandafter{\endfoo}}
\fbox{%
  \begin{foo}{ccc}
    \hline
    Test & a & b \\
    \hline
  \end{foo}
}
\end{document}
```

This has come up for example in [`xparse` development](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/c73ec0dc7651a3d012e96e7aa699597ee56fb474).

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Luckily this doesn't seem to impact my use case either =D